# How to replace multiple items at once? [python]

Tags: python, text, replace

I want to use make replacements on a text file which is

`one two three pthree two ptwo one two ...(1000+ words)`

such that output looks like `1 2 3 p3 2 p2 1 2 ....`

My code looks like

```py
dict = { 'zero':'0','one':'1','two':'2','three':'3','four':'4','five':'5','six':'6','seven':'7'}
x = 'one two three pthree two ptwo one two' #reading input from file
for k, v in dict.items():
    x = x.replace(k, v)
```

I have tried these solutions [str.replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62429677/how-to-use-str-replace-to-replace-multiple-pairs-at-once?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string?noredirect=1&lq=1) but both methods give me the same error which is

```
TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not int
```

What does this error mean? And how should I resolve it?
Thank You

Comment: The code you posted works without any errors though.

Comment: Yep, seems to be working, see https://repl.it/@ChristianBauman/WoozyAggressiveUnix

Comment: `TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not int` Well this error just tells you that you need to put in a `str` type but you are giving it `int`. Try first converting it to `str` using `str()` function. Probably you're not  just providing much details on your question.

Comment: Also, it replaces every occurance. For ex: `'phone'` will be `'ph1'`, which you might not be anticipating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the code you have written in the question actually works. From the error I suspect that the dictionary you are actually working against is more like:

```
{ 'zero': 0, 'one': 1 } # etc
```

I.E the values are integers rather than strings. You can either correct whatever is creating the dictionary to ensure that the values have the right type, or you can cast to the correct type before calling replace

```py
d = { 'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 }
x = 'one two three pthree two ptwo one two' #reading input from file
for k, v in d.items():
    x = x.replace(k, str(v))
```